# Select with UNION ALL and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I've trying to query from a few tables with `UNION ALL` but I get this error on the ORDER clause:

> `#1054 - Unknown column 'Time' in 'order clause'`

I have column `Time` in the table. This is the query:

```
SELECT * from
(SELECT table, 'as'  from as
   UNION ALL
 SELECT table, 'as'  from as1
   UNION ALL
 SELECT table, 'as'  from as2
   UNION ALL
 SELECT table, 'as'  from as3) asAllWrong
 WHERE table not like 'as%' OR length(table) < 12
 ORDER BY Time='2015-06-02 9:00:00;
```

So, how exactly I can query this to show me all wrong entry from those tables and this table? 
And why did I get this error even if there is a column called `Time`?

Edit: My mistake they are different tables as, as1, as2... And I want to query all wrong entries in that time as I said.

EDIT: This is what is look like now and is working good so far. Note that this is for me.. will not go in any production and will be used sometimes so I don't really need performance .. etc..

```
SELECT * from
( SELECT as.*, 'as'  from as
   UNION ALL
 SELECT as1.*, 'as1'  from as1
   UNION ALL
 SELECT as2.*, 'as2'  from as2
   UNION ALL
 SELECT as3.*, 'as3'  from as3) asAllWrong
 WHERE as not like 'as%' OR length(as) < 12
 ORDER BY Time='2015-06-02 9:00:00' ASC;
```

Comment: could you add your table structures and some test data?

Comment: You never select  a column names time. so you can not order by them.

Comment: What do you think the ORDER BY clause is supposed to do?  You ORDER BY expressions.  I suppose you might have expected to get all the values where the time is not 09:00 on the 2nd of June before those where the time is, but it is a pretty unusual ORDER BY condition.  Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: `ORDER BY Time='2015-06-02 9:00:00;` is syntactically wrong - you can `ORDER BY Time` or select by `Time='2015-06-02 9:00:00;'`, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Also, your UNION seems to be selecting the same data four times.  What is the advantage of that?

Comment: Plenty of errors here. The only thing right is the alias name of the result: `asAllWrong`.

Comment: @Smutje: It's not syntactically wrong in MySQL (read Jonathan Leffler's comment above yours), it just makes little sense and may not be what the OP is after.

Comment: Your edit hasn't helped much.  You have `SELECT table, 'as'  from as` (followed by a UNION ALL).  That means you are selecting a column called `table` and a string containing `'as'` from a table called `as`.  Since both TABLE and AS are SQL keywords, you're likely to find you need to enclose them in back-quotes (in MySQL; in standard SQL, you'd enclose them in double quotes).  And although you've changed the constant string, you've not really done much to the queries.  You should show the outline schemas of the table(s) involved.  You've not explained what makes an entry 'wrong', either.

Comment: Well .. I'm confusing even more now. I just want to query 4 tables and check for this where condition. And may be the time must be also in WHERE condition?

Answer (score 2):

While the query looks very confusing, the bottom line is that your result in-memory table created via `UNION ALL` doesn't contain the field `Time` and that's why you have an error.

As for why it's not there, normally you can't just `select {table_name}`. It has to be a list of columns. But I am not an expert in MySql - it may allow such trickery. As Jonathan noted below, you'd be better of with:

```
select table.Time, 'as' from table
union all...
```

This would definitely bring `Time` field into the picture.

Comment: You can use `SELECT table.* FROM table` (though here the table seems to be named `as`, except `as` is a keyword, so that isn't going to fly, I think).

Comment: That surely makes it more syntactically correct statement :) `select table.*, 'as' from table UNION ALL...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify also the `Time` column in your select

```
SELECT * from
(SELECT table, Time, 'as'  from as
   UNION ALL
 SELECT table, Time, 'as'  from as
   UNION ALL
 SELECT table, Time, 'as'  from as
   UNION ALL
 SELECT table, Time, 'as'  from as) asAllWrong
 WHERE table not like 'as%' OR length(table) < 12
 ORDER BY Time='2015-06-02 9:00:00' ASC/DESC;
```

This should work.

EDIT: Thank's for pointing my errors. I just use his example to show it.

Also as other said already you can user `select as.*, 'as' from as...` this will select all fields from `as` if you need them of course.

Also you may need `ASC` or `DESC` in your `ORDER BY` clause. `ORDER BY` sorts the records in ascending order by default.

Comment: You might get away with that; you might need to use back-quotes around `Time`.  But you've not explained what the ORDER BY is supposed to be doing, and it looks pretty damn weird.  And, in all honesty, I think it is pretty unlikely to work.

Comment: The `order by` clause is syntactically wrong - it contains an unbalanced single quote.